# Null checking the array in flutter

Tags: android, flutter

I'm trying to compare my phone contacts against a list of phone numbers. In my phone contacts, I may have invalid contacts. Here I am trying to null-check the phone array but It throws an error. Do any suggestions pls? Thanks in advance [image: screenshot]

Comment: could you please provide snippet code instead of screenShot image?

Answer (score 0):

Because the `simcontact?.phones` can be null. So use the `?.elementAt` or `?[]` rather than the only `[]` operator.

```dart
List<String>? nullableList = null;

final element = nullableList?.elementAt(0);
final element2 = nullableList?[0];
```

Answer (score 0):

your code...

```
var tempsearchResult =
    simcontacts.cast().firstWhere((simcontact) => flattenPhoneNumber(simcontact?.phones[0].value) == ...);
```

modify as...

```
var tempsearchResult = simcontacts.cast().firstWhere((simcontact) {
  if (simcontact?.phones?.length > 0) {
    return flattenPhoneNumber(simcontact?.phones?[0].value) == 123 /*your comparison value*/;
  }
  return false;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the list of phones can be empty. Accessing the first element then will throw an error then.

Try writing instead of

```
simcontact?.phones[0].value
```

write

```
simcontact?.phones?.firstOrNull?.value
```

This will need the following import to use `firstOrNull`

```
import 'package:collection/collection.dart';
```